# .NET Core application debug error: "Unable to set the next statement. This file does not exactly match the original version."

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

While debugging a *.NET Core* console application in VS 2017, I'm unable to make an edit and then set the next statement.  It gives me the error mentioned in the title:

[image]

For example, if I set the breakpoint where indicated by the comment, then debug, and modify the string in the first line directly above the breakpoint, I get the error:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string x = "foo"; // modify this after debug breaks.
    string y = "bar"; // breakpoint here
}
```

**NOTE:** this works as expected in a *.NET Framework* console application.

When I google the title of this OP, I get zero results, even if I split the two sentences from the error message into separate quoted strings.  When I google without quotes, I get a number of results that don't provide an an answer.  For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455046/unable-to-set-next-statement-when-debugging) is similar in that it starts out with "Unable to set the next statement" but then the rest is different.  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905730/unable-to-set-the-next-statement-the-next-statement-cannot-be-changed-at-this-t) is also similar but again is different after the first sentence.

What is causing this?

Comment: Just a hunch, but have you tried toggling your "Enable Edit and Continue" debug option? I really have no idea if that's related, but something I'd check.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried it and it didn't change the behavior.

Comment: Are you directly modifying the code, or modifying "x" in the Immediate Window? I am not sure of your original problem, but maybe that would be a helpful workaround? You should be able to type 'x = "newFoo"' in the Immediate Window.

Comment: I'm directly modifying it.  Your workaround didn't work but it did lead me to another workaround, which was to set the next line first and *then* modify the value of `x`.  It doesn't work when I modify `x` and then try to set the next line.

Comment: Can anyone repro this?  Or is it just me?

Comment: Having the same issue (VS 2019). Has anyone figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error message. I don't know why it worked but I resolved it by:

1. Checking `Options->Debugging->General->Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators`.
2. Running a debug session (where I could then edit and continue).

After unchecking the flag again everything was still working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Delete the output folder (bin\debug).
2. Close the IDE.
3. Open the Project again.
4. Run the project.

Sometimes Visual Studio IDE lock a file.
Or try running Visual Studio IDE as administrator.